# Resigning within a few months of accepting new job?

Tags: professionalism, ethics, resignation

After almost a year of unemployment, things really looked up in early Jan when I got called up for an interview for a large government organisation.

I also applied for my 'dream job' at another company. I went out of my way to connect with people there and made sure to make an impression. I even found out that my old classmate was working in the same division and I actually met up with her and she took me on a tour and I met my future-bosses in person. But I still had to go through the whole formal job application process so I did that and waited. My friend told me that the whole process would take about 3 to 5 months.

Meanwhile, the large govn organisation called back and offered me the job. I decided to take it up coz unemployment sucks. I signed on the dotted line and I'm now an employee!

And yesterday, my 'dream job' company called me back for an interview. I'm thrilled and nervous. I really really want my dream job and I made sure to let them know that I'm very keen on the job as well. I think they like me, frankly and I'm like 80% sure that I will get the job. However, should I feel guilty about resigning from my current government job within the next couple of months? I feel like I acted unethically by accepting this job.

How would I even go about explaining my resignation?

Comment: "I think they like me, frankly and I'm like 80% sure that I will get the job." - wait until you're 100% sure (i.e. you have a concrete offer with start date) before doing anything.

Comment: To echo @Brandin, you don't have a dream job offer, you have an interview. When (if) you have a **written** job offer then you have a job offer. When you accept the written job offer, you have an actual job. Are  you planning on resigning now from your job for a "non-job"?

Answer (score 0):

You don't owe it to any company or organisation to pass up on a fantastic opportunity, and I'm sure your current employer will be able to empathize with that.

I have to disagree with the answer from Bjarke Søgaard. Just because you've signed on the dotted line doesn't mean you have an obligation to stay at the company for any amount of time. Often companies will not want to waste resources training people that are going to leave very quickly and so will not choose to offer you the job, but at the time of you accepting the offer you hadn't done so as a place holder for this dream job - I mean, did you even know they were going to 100% call you back?

In addition to this there are many reasons to leave a company within the first few months. Perhaps you're not a proper cultural fit, perhaps the role wasn't fully explained to you and you don't like what you're actually doing, perhaps family obligations arise or you have to relocate, etc.

I do feel like you're jumping the gun a little by beginning to pen your resignation letter before you've even interviewed. But confidence is key and I wish you luck. You're resignation should thank the organization for the opportunity that they gave you, perhaps explain where you're going and why, and wish the company/your colleagues the best of luck. It's poilte, respectful and honest, and that's all you can ask for in a resignation letter.

Comment: Government jobs, at least in the U.S. have a minimum contract term that's always outlined in the advertisement for the position, so you know what you're getting into. Severing the contract leaves you at risk for obtaining "ineligible for rehire" status for some set amount of time, so without a sense of 100% on dream job, there's some potential to put yourself between a rock and a hard place.